# Nav item flickering after adding negative top margin

Tags: html, css, html-lists, navbar, flicker

I'm trying to get rid of the flickering I'm getting after I added negative top margin (so that it would be visible above my navbar) to my < li > item. Here's the JSFiddle's link: http://fiddle.jshell.net/xv6mk/.  
And the code just in case. 
HTML:

```
<ul>
        <li>Main</li>
        <li>Subpage 1</li>
        <li>Subpage 2</li>
        <li>Subpage 3</li>
        <li>About</li>
</ul>
```

And CSS:

```
ul {
display: inline;
list-style: none;
}
li {
font-size: 16px;
display: inline-block;
margin-right: -6px;
padding: 16px;
cursor: pointer;
display:inline-block;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
li:hover {
background: white;
color: #74DF00;
border-top: 10px solid #525458;
margin-top: -10px;
}
```

I will really appreciate help :) .

EDIT: Adding this 2 lines to < li > item (not only hover) works like charm. Thank you :) .

```
border-top: 10px solid #848484;
margin-top: -10px;
```

Comment: @DanielLisik perhaps `border-color:transparent` would be better than `#fff` incase of later page bg colour change :D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the transition property, you are transitioning everything, try the following:

```
transition-property: color, border-top, background;
```

Just add the prefixes for cross browser support.

Fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/xv6mk/3/